# Model observer in Laravel 4, restore() triggering both restored() and updated()

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm using an observer on models in Laravel 4 for the purposes of keeping historical records of changes made by each user. The code I'm currently using is as follows:

```
class BaseObserver {

    public function __construct(){}

    public function saving(Eloquent $model){}

    public function saved(Eloquent $model){}

    public function updating(Eloquent $model){}

    public function updated(Eloquent $model)
    {
        $this->storeAuditData($model, 'update');
    }

    public function creating(Eloquent $model){}

    public function created(Eloquent $model)
    {
         $this->storeAuditData($model, 'create');
    }

    public function deleting(Eloquent $model){}

    public function deleted(Eloquent $model)
    {
        $this->storeAuditData($model, 'delete');
    }

    public function restoring(Eloquent $model){}

    public function restored(Eloquent $model)
    {
         $this->storeAuditData($model, 'restore');
    }

    public function storeAuditData(Eloquent $model, $action)
    {
        $snapshot = array();
        foreach ($model->fillable as $fieldName) {
            $snapshot[$fieldName] = $model->$fieldName;
        }

        $auditData = new AuditData;
        $auditData->model = get_class($model);
        $auditData->rowId = $model->id;
        $auditData->action = $action;
        $auditData->user = Auth::user()->username;
        $auditData->moment = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $auditData->snapshot = json_encode($snapshot);
        $auditData->save();

    }

}
```

This works fine, except when a *restore()* is performed, both the *restored* and *updated* methods get run, so I end up with two rows in the AuditData database table, when I only want one (the "restore").

Is there any way I can tell within the *updated* method whether the update is a restore or not, and only store the audit data if it is a stand-alone update and not a restore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if only the `deleted_at` column has been modified (is *dirty*)

```
public function updated(Eloquent $model)
{
    if($model->isDirty($model->getDeletedAtColumn()) && count($model->getDirty()) == 1){
        // only soft deleting column changed
    }
    else {
        $this->storeAuditData($model, 'update');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue nicely. I needed to change `getDeletedAtColumn` to `getDeletedAtColumn()`, but other than that it was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

While restoring, and using Laravel auto timestamps, the column `updated_at` will be modified along with `deleted_at`. To differentiate between 'restored' and 'updated' observer event, within `updated` method I use:

```php
public function updated(Eloquent $model)
{
    if ($model->isDirty($model->getDeletedAtColumn())
        && $model->{$model->getDeletedAtColumn()} === null
        && $model->getOriginal($model->getDeletedAtColumn()) !== null) {

        // model was restored
    }
}
```